# Difference between workers and processes in uwsgi

Tags: uwsgi

I am trying to be careful and understand every setting in my nginx configuration. I have seen a configuration example that has something like:

```
workers = 8
processes = 10
```

But the uWSGI docs do not seem to differentiate. Are they synonyms? If so, does that make this configuration incorrect?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`workers` and `processes` are indeed synonyms and the same thing. (I'm sure you've seen the [configuration option documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#processes) for them both)

That configuration is very incorrect and could actually have *no* effect as a result. (I just found out that by having the `cheaper` option twice in one of my `ini` files neither was being picked up - but I don't know if this is the case with workers/processes).

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link

Comment: i think one of the options is there for backwards compatibility...I may be wrong though :-)