# Does uWSGI start all processes at boot time?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have several apps running on uWSGI. Most of them grow in memory usage over time. I've always attributed this to a memory leak that I hadn't tracked down. But lately I've noticed that the growth is quite chunky. I'm wondering if each chunk correlates with a process being started.

Does uWSGI start all processes at boot time, or does it only start up a new one when there are enough requests coming in to make it necessary?

Here's an example config:

```
[uwsgi]
strict = true

wsgi-file = foo.py
callable = app

die-on-term = true

http-socket = :2345

master = true
enable-threads = true
thunder-lock = true
processes = 6
threads = 1

memory-report = true
```

**update:** this looks relevant: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Cheaper.html

Does "worker" mean the same thing as "process" (answer seems to be [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053721/168143))? If so then it seems like if I want the number to remain constant always, I should do:

```
cheaper = 6
cheaper-initial = 6
processes = 6
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, uWSGI will start all processes (or workers - worker is an alias for process in uWSGI config) at boot time but it will depend on your application what will go from then. If application imports all modules at boot time, it should be fully loaded before first request, but if some modules are loaded on request time, each worker will be fully loaded only after first requests (assuming that any request will load all modules. If not, it will be fully loaded only after doing combination of requests that will load all of it).

But even after loading all modules, application memory usage won't be constant. There may be some logging, global variables, debug information etc accumulating on every request. If you're using any framework it is possible that it will save some data for debugging, statistics etc.

By default, cheaper is not enabled - that means uWSGI will spawn all workers at startup. If you want to use cheaper mode, you need to define at least `cheaper` parameter. More about usage of cheaper system you can find in [documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cheaper.html)

There are many other systems built in uWSGI to control load based on requests amount. For example

- [uWSGI Legion subsystem](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Legion.html)
- [On demand vassals](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/OnDemandVassals.html)
- Socket activation ([with inetd/xinetd](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Inetd.html), [with upstart](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Upstart.html#socket-activation-from-ubuntu-12-04), [with systemd](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html#socket-activation), [with circus](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Circus.html#socket-activation) or mentioned above on demand vassals when running emperor mode)
- [Bloodlord mode](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Broodlord.html)
- [Zerg mode](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Zerg.html)

If you're worried that uWSGI will take up too much resources, there are solutions for that too:

- [Running uWSGI in a Linux CGroup](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cgroups.html)
- [Linux Namespaces](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Namespaces.html)
- Or even running [docker instances](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docker)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I knew about module loading and other things affecting memory growth, I was just wondering about the process booting. Do you know what the Cheaper settings are for?

Comment: Cheaper setting will prevent spawning workers at startup, instead doing it at first request. It allows you to specify how many workers will be spawned at startup, how many workers can be spawned on requests (if needed) and if workers spawned on requests should be automatically killed if not needed anymore.

Comment: Is cheaper the default system that uwsgi uses and these settings configure its behavior, or is it a special mode that is activated when you use the settings?

Comment: It's not default, you must use it explicitly.

Comment: What is the reason to use cheaper? And where can I read documentation about the default behavior?

Comment: I don't think that there is any documentation for default behavior, because it's pretty straightforward and in [documentation of cheaper](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cheaper.html) it is explicitly said that you must add `cheaper` parameter to enable it. Reason for use cheaper is if you're want to save some resources if there is not much traffic on your website (for example if you're charged for used resources or you have more than one app on server and it is unlikely to have both on huge traffic at same time).

Comment: I've noticed that you're might be worried about resources usage and scaling of your apps, so I've expanded my answer with solutions for controlling load of your apps based on requests and limiting resource usage.